# How to send a file using API

Tags: cypress

I am trying to upload a file using API to an app. However, it does not work and returns a timeout error.

[image: error.png]
[image: fileUpload.spec.js]

Comment: Its hard to help without revealing the api docs. Make sure to supply all the required data and your authorization token is valid.

Comment: The required data is already supplied but I do not have an idea of the structure for uploading documents using an API using cy.request